# How to scrape a certain text regardless of which tags it is contained in using scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a number of sites to find if a certain code snippet is present. Most of the time the scraper works perfectly as intended.

I am using the following method to find the bit of code I am looking for:

```
...
item["foo"] = response.xpath("//script[contains(text(), 'fooscript')]")

...
if len(item["foo"]) != 0:
    doStuff()
```

However, my issue is the following: sometimes the thing I want to find is not in the script itself but as the source for the script (I know how to scrape this as well), and sometimes when JQuery is used, I can't get the correct scrape results.

So my question is, is there an easier way to look through the raw HTML/JS text to find a match for what I am looking for? Trying to look through all alternatives to scrapes will quickly bloat up the code, and I only need to see if this certain text is present. I have not found a suitable method from the official scrapy documentation (though I am still somewhat inexperienced with the tool, so I might have missed it), so if anyone has a solution for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simple regex search through the HTML source is what you are looking for? Something like

```
if re.search(r'fooscript', response.text):
    doStuff()
```

Or, if you just know it's wrapped inside some element and just don't know which, you can do

```
item["foo"] = response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'fooscript')]")
```

Also, you don't need to use `len` to check the result, simply

```
if item["foo"]:
    doStuff()
```

is enough.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much.